# "И вот" общее для данного ССП? Запятую отменяет?

Tags: пунктуация

> И вот расставлены фигуры и партия в разгаре!

Comment: «В разгаре» партия в начале игры быть не может. Не логично. Как с костром, к примеру.

Comment: Давай ответ, пятёрку поставлю! )))

Comment: Устал. Не думаю, что одинок.

Comment: Ну и жадюга. Мог бы коммент скопировать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лучше так:

***Но вот расставлены фигуры -- и битва началась!***

Answer (score 0):

Хоть и с большим запозданием, но внесу свою "копейку" (ВПОЛНЕ допускаю, что кривую).
Партия не может быть в разгаре одновременно с расстановкой фигур, разгар партии является следствием (последствием) расстановки фигур, то есть у этих действий не может быть общего члена, показывающего одновременность.
Мне кажется, возможен вариант: И вот расставлены фигуры... и партия в разгаре!
Или такой: И вот расставлены фигуры, и вот партия в разгаре! Запятая как раз покажет, что прошло время между действиями, и останется акцент "и вот".